# Print only True elements in JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, json

using java script I'm required to add attributes to a list in an html page depending on the value of the attribute in the JSON array.
The array is formatted like this :
'

```
var yelp= {
"attributes": {
    "Take-out": true,
    "Drive-Thru": false,
    "Good For": {
        "dessert": false,
        "latenight": true,
        "lunch": true,
        "dinner": true,
        "brunch": true,
        "breakfast": true
    },
    "Caters": false,
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Takes Reservations": true,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Ambience": {
        "romantic": true,
        "intimate": false,
        "classy": false,
        "hipster": true,
        "divey": false,
        "touristy": false,
        "trendy": true,
        "upscale": false,
        "casual": true
    },
    "Parking": {
        "garage": false,
        "street": true,
        "validated": false,
        "lot": true,
        "valet": false
    },
    "Has TV": true,
    "Outdoor Seating": true,
    "Attire": "casual",
    "Alcohol": "none",
    "Waiter Service": true,
    "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
    "Good for Kids": true,
    "Good For Groups": true,
    "Price Range": 2
},
"type": "business"
```

}

essentially I want to print all the values that = true,
i tried using an if statement like:
 `if (yelp.attributes.Take-out == true)
    output.innerHTML+= "Take-out <br>;` 
it did not work

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** I'm assuming you are actually working with an array of `yelp` objects rather than a single `yelp` object. If this is the case, note that I wrapped your `yelp` object in brackets `[]` to make it an array.

When you have json property names with hyphens or spaces, for example, you cannot access them like you are `yelp.attributes.Take-out`. You have to use bracket notation like so `yelp.attributes['Take-out']` Otherwise, JavaScript will translate that to math: `yelp.attributes.Take - out`.

If not, instead of trying to loop through the object, just access the property directly. (See the second example)

You can use `Array.filter` to find what you're looking for:

```js
var yelp = [{
  "attributes": {
    "Take-out": true,
    "Drive-Thru": false,
    "Good For": {
      "dessert": false,
      "latenight": true,
      "lunch": true,
      "dinner": true,
      "brunch": true,
      "breakfast": true
    },
    "Caters": false,
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Takes Reservations": true,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Ambience": {
      "romantic": true,
      "intimate": false,
      "classy": false,
      "hipster": true,
      "divey": false,
      "touristy": false,
      "trendy": true,
      "upscale": false,
      "casual": true
    },
    "Parking": {
      "garage": false,
      "street": true,
      "validated": false,
      "lot": true,
      "valet": false
    },
    "Has TV": true,
    "Outdoor Seating": true,
    "Attire": "casual",
    "Alcohol": "none",
    "Waiter Service": true,
    "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
    "Good for Kids": true,
    "Good For Groups": true,
    "Price Range": 2
  },
  "type": "business"
}];

const takeOuts = yelp.filter(y => y.attributes['Take-out'] === true);
console.log(takeOuts);
```

If you're just working with a single object and you want to determine if it's `Take out` or not, access it directly:

```js
var yelp = {
  "attributes": {
    "Take-out": true,
    "Drive-Thru": false,
    "Good For": {
      "dessert": false,
      "latenight": true,
      "lunch": true,
      "dinner": true,
      "brunch": true,
      "breakfast": true
    },
    "Caters": false,
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Takes Reservations": true,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Ambience": {
      "romantic": true,
      "intimate": false,
      "classy": false,
      "hipster": true,
      "divey": false,
      "touristy": false,
      "trendy": true,
      "upscale": false,
      "casual": true
    },
    "Parking": {
      "garage": false,
      "street": true,
      "validated": false,
      "lot": true,
      "valet": false
    },
    "Has TV": true,
    "Outdoor Seating": true,
    "Attire": "casual",
    "Alcohol": "none",
    "Waiter Service": true,
    "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
    "Good for Kids": true,
    "Good For Groups": true,
    "Price Range": 2
  },
  "type": "business"
};

console.log(yelp.attributes['Take-out'] === true);
```

Answer (score -1):

`Take-out` is not a valid identifier, you need to use `[]` notation to access the property in such case

```js
var yelp = {"attributes": {"Take-out": true,"Drive-Thru": false,"Good For": {"dessert": false,"latenight": true,"lunch": true,"dinner": true,"brunch": true,"breakfast": true},"Caters": false,"Noise Level": "average","Takes Reservations": true,"Delivery": false,"Ambience": {"romantic": true,"intimate": false,"classy": false,"hipster": true,"divey": false,"touristy": false,"trendy": true,"upscale": false,"casual": true},"Parking": {"garage": false,"street": true,"validated": false,"lot": true,"valet": false},"Has TV": true,"Outdoor Seating": true,"Attire": "casual","Alcohol": "none","Waiter Service": true,"Accepts Credit Cards": true,"Good for Kids": true,"Good For Groups": true,"Price Range": 2},"type": "business"}

console.log(yelp.attributes["Take-out"])
```

Answer (score -1):

The object may have deep hierarchy so *recursion* looks useful in this case. Something like this.

```js
var yelp = {
  "attributes": {
    "Take-out": true,
    "Drive-Thru": false,
    "Good For": {
      "dessert": false,
      "latenight": true,
      "lunch": true,
      "dinner": true,
      "brunch": true,
      "breakfast": true
    },
    "Caters": false,
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Takes Reservations": true,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Ambience": {
      "romantic": true,
      "intimate": false,
      "classy": false,
      "hipster": true,
      "divey": false,
      "touristy": false,
      "trendy": true,
      "upscale": false,
      "casual": true
    },
    "Parking": {
      "garage": false,
      "street": true,
      "validated": false,
      "lot": true,
      "valet": false
    },
    "Has TV": true,
    "Outdoor Seating": true,
    "Attire": "casual",
    "Alcohol": "none",
    "Waiter Service": true,
    "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
    "Good for Kids": true,
    "Good For Groups": true,
    "Price Range": 2
  },
  "type": "business"
};

function parseYelp(obj, prefix) {
  if (prefix)
    prefix += ': ';
  else
    prefix = '';
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object')
      parseYelp(obj[key], prefix + key);
    else if (obj[key] === true)
      console.log(prefix + key);
  }
}
parseYelp(yelp);
//or just attributes
console.log('\nattributes only\n');
parseYelp(yelp.attributes);
```